# The train-and-platform VS Causality and Simultaneity

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers, causality, thought-experiment

for long time I was ruminating on the train and platform experiment and “what if” extension of this experiment…

So, what if the light striking on either end triggers system (one on each end) with moving scythe which will kill the man in the center of the train.

But the moving scythes can only kill him if they are not triggered simultaneously. Lets assume there is a mechanical system that avoids touching the scythes (scythes are moving against each other, both moving towards center)

My implication:

The man in the train would survive because the scythes would start moving towards him at the same moment but as far as they are not allowed to touch eachother they would stop before reaching his neck.

The man in the train would be dead from the point of view of the observer on platform because the scythes would start moving at different moment thus one reaching him sooner as the other one.

So is he in some kind of superposition alive and dead at the same time? If the train stops and the man from the platform would go and check on the other man would he find him dead or ok? Which of my assumption is wrong and why?

Answer (score 3):

No, you misunderstand. Either the lightning can strike the two ends of the train simultaneously in the frame of the train- in which case it strikes at two different times in the frame of the platform- or it can strike simultaneously in the frame of the platform- in which case it strikes at two different times in the frame of the train.

When you say the scythes will kill the man unless they are triggered simultaneously, you need to specify which frame they are synchronised with. If the scythes are synchronised in the frame of the train, and the lightning strikes simultaneously in the frame of the train, then the man will survive. If the scythes are synchronised with the frame of the platform, and the lightning strikes simultaneously in the frame of the train, then the lightning will strike at two different times in the platform frame and the scythes will kill the man.

Comment: Thanks! This seem to be pretty logical answer. So if the mechanism is “synchronised in the frame of the train, and the lightning strikes simultaneously in the frame of the train, then the man will survive” the observer on the platform would see scythes start to move at the same time? Although the light would not hit both ends at the same time from his frame

Comment: No, if the scythes start simultaneously in the frame of the train, they will start at two different times in the frame of the platform.

Comment: thanks again, but then if they start at two different times in the frame of platform than outcome should be that the scythes will kill the man in train. That should be my observation from the platform frame. Am I right?

Comment: No, not if you have programmed the scythes to take account if time in the frame of the train, where they start simultaneously. The fact that they start at different times in other frames is irrelevant. What counts is how you have programmed the scythes and how the lightning strikes in relation to that.

Comment: The observer on the platform sees that the scythes start at different times and don't kill the man because they have been programmed that way.